# JAR inter-dependencies inside WAR with ant

Tags: deployment, jar, war

We have to package (using ant) a war file to be deployed (on tomcat )
Inside the lib folders, there are several jar files:

- 3rd-party-lib-A.jar
- 3rd-party-lib-B.jar
- 3rd-party-lib-C.jar
- ...etc

Such that lib-A depends on lib-B ...etc

The WAR is deployed fine, but cannot be started because errors likes this happen:

```
INFO: ExtensionValidator[/MyWebApp][3rd-party-lib-A.jar]: Required extension "lib-B" not found
INFO: ExtensionValidator[/MyWebApp][3rd-party-lib-A.jar]: Required extension "lib-C" not found
```

..etc

inside the manifest file of "3rd-party-lib-A.jar" we can find:
...

```
lib-B-Extension-Name: lib-B
lib-B-Implementation-Version: 1.1
lib-B-Implementation-URL: http://10.10.1.148/bundle/3rd-party-lib-B.jar
log4j-Extension-Name: log4j
log4j-Implementation-Version: 1.2.9
log4j-Implementation-URL: http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j
```

...

My question is, how to go from here?
 1) repackage each jar to have a manifest with class-path, using relative path? 
 2) put the jars in the tomcat lib?
 3) read the manual? :) 
 4) use maven?

thanks

Comment: I'm putting this in a comment, because it doesn't really solve your problem, but I've been working with maven for years now and I rarely run into any dependency issues. Your 1st option isn't a good solution to any problem, your 2nd option also isn't really a good solution, I'm guessing that you've tried your 3rd option...

Comment: I haven't tried maven for this case, but it seems a plausible solution like in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897843/packaging-jar-file-in-war-file]